# iOS How to refresh UIWebView at didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, uiwebview, refresh, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way that I can refresh or reload UIWebView when new notification arrived ?

I have been trying to search the answer but nothing so far.

Someone who knows this please help me.

Thanks

I tried as following but nothing...

At AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadWebView:)
                                                 name:@"PUSH_NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
}
```

And Put below code at MainViewController.m

```
-(void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification*) notification
{
[_webView reload];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

I am fairly newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved...

My scenario is to refresh webview when new push notification arrives.

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadWebView" object:nil];
}
```

And in ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadWebView:)
                                             name:@"reloadWebView" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload
{
[self unregisterForNotifications];
}

-(void)reloadWebView:(NSNotification*) notification
{
[_webView reload];
}

-(void)unregisterForNotifications
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"reloadWebView" object:nil];
}
```

Works well.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh UIWebView, you can call reload on instance. However, I think you know that and need a way to call it wen notification arrives. I would suggest using broadcast mechanism here:
- send it when remote notification arrived 
- register broadcast handler in view controller that owns web view & refresh web view in registered selector

You can find info how to use broadcasts in many tutorials, for example this one http://hayageek.com/nsnotification-nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/